# Why does Java throw a InputMismatchException when I input a float in the terminal?

Tags: java

I have this simple program.

```
package com.company;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter a float: ");
        float a = scanner.nextFloat();

        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

I input 4.3

```
Enter a float: 4.3
```

I get this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextFloat(Scanner.java:2496)
    at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:11)
```

why? float a = scanner.nextFloat(); is a match in my mind.

Any clarification would be much appreciated.
I'm using Java Development Kit 17.

Comment: Its most likely due to your locale. `nextFloat()` is locale specific. So for example in germany you have to enter `4,3` (comma, not dot)

Comment: See the linked duplicate (and more similar questions) for how to approach it.

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly what caused the issue

Comment: Interestingly enough, on Java 8 your code worked, but on Java 11 and up (I haven't tried 9 or 10) I also need to use 4,3.

Comment: I also ran it but I did not give me any error...